# PRIME GPU offloading results in a snow crash

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, amd-graphics

I have lubuntu 18.04 on Dell Vostro 3450 with hybrid graphic cards - Intel integrated card and AMD Radeon HD 6600M. I've been trying to use PRIME to play some games - particularly Morrowind on OpenMW engine, but it seems that every time I try, it results in a video of just chaotic snowy thingy and bars of black flashing on screen in high frequency. I also tried it with glxgears with result very much the same.

I used this tutorial:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PRIME

Output of console during runtime is "radeon: The kernel rejected CS, see dmesg for more information. (-16)"

I DID NOT download new open source drivers, even tough it's stated in the tutorial, because I'm linux newbie and simply don't know how. I'm not sure if drivers in the tutorial are even ubuntu compatible. I've checked the apt for new drivers and it showed me, that I have those drivers installed automatically:
xserver-xorg-video-ati
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu

Every help much appreciated!
Thanks!